# Chamando função que esta dentro de outra

Tags: javascript, html

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Caixa Eletrônico
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://icon-icons.com/icons2/516/PNG/512/cash_icon-icons.com_51090.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="estilo_caixa.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Java_caixa_eletronico.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="cabecalho">
        <img src="http://ganhardinheiropassoapasso.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/finance-634901_640-e1437792408793.png?x21126"> 
    </div>
    <div id="cabecalho2">
        <font color="white" size="36">Banco Nacional</font>
    </div>
    <div id="cabecalho">
        <img src="http://ganhardinheiropassoapasso.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/finance-634901_640-e1437792408793.png?x21126"> 
    </div>
    <div id="corpo">
        <h1>Retirada de dinheiro</h1>
        <form>
            Valor do saque R$: <input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui" id="valor">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Consultar" name="Consulta" onclick="Calcula()">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <hr color="white" size="3">
            <h4>Depois de clicar no botão "Consultar" siga o link abaixo:</h4>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <a href="notas.html">Verificar o saque</a>
        </form>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Função no Javascript:

```
function Calcula() {

var valor_digitado = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
var q_100 = 0;
var q_50 = 0;
var q_20 = 0;
var q_10 = 0;
var q_5 = 0;
var q_2 = 0;
var q_1 = 0;

while (valor_digitado != 0){ 

    if ((valor_digitado%100) == 0) {

        q_100 = q_100 + 1;
        valor_digitado = (valor_digitado - 100);
    }

    else if ((valor_digitado%50) == 0) {

        q_50 = q_50 + 1;
        valor_digitado = (valor_digitado - 50);
    }

    else if ((valor_digitado%20) == 0) {

        q_20 = q_20 + 1;
        valor_digitado = (valor_digitado - 20);
    }

    else if ((valor_digitado%10) == 0) {

        q_10 = q_10 + 1;
        valor_digitado = (valor_digitado - 10);
    }

    else if ((valor_digitado%5) == 0) {

        q_5 = q_5 + 1;
        valor_digitado = (valor_digitado - 5);
    }

    else if ((valor_digitado%2) == 0) {

        q_2 = q_2 + 1;
        valor_digitado = (valor_digitado - 2);
    }

    else {

        q_1 = q_1 + 1;
        valor_digitado = (valor_digitado - 1);
    }
}

function escreve100(){

    alert("Quantidade de notas de 100: "+q_100);
}

function escreve50(){

    alert("Quantidade de notas de 50: "+q_50);
}

function escreve20(){

    alert("Quantidade de notas de 20: "+q_20);
}

function escreve10(){

    alert("Quantidade de notas de 10: "+q_10);
}

function escreve5(){

    alert("Quantidade de notas de 5: "+q_5);
}

function escreve2(){

    alert("Quantidade de notas de 2: "+q_2);
}

function escreve1(){

    alert("Quantidade de moedas de 1: "+q_1);
}
}
```

Quero chamar cada uma dessas funções "escreve" em botoes no html, mas não estou conseguindo. Os botoes estão todos assim e deveriam chamar um alert contendo a quantidade de notas, o que não está acontecendo, com suas respectivas funções (esse é o botão que deveria mostrar a quantidade de notas de cem):

```
<input type="submit" value="Mostrar quant. notas de 100" name="quan100" 
onclick="escreve100()">
```

Comment: "Não está conseguindo" por quê? Aliás, essa repetição de código é muito desnecessária. Você deveria melhorar isso.

Comment: Quando aperto o botão, o alert com a quantidade de notas não é exibido

Comment: Porque ele tenta fazer `submit`, troca esses input por botões normais.

Comment: Subtitui type="submit" por type="button", mas a mensagem ainda não esta sendo exibida

Comment: aonde está o elemento com `id="valor"`?

Comment: É de outro arquivo html, vou coloca-lo acima